# JQuery. If one dropdown option selected, then other dropdown option selected automatically

Tags: jquery, html-select

Here is my scenario.

The following is shown to users and they can select one.

```
<select class="user-select"> 
  <option value="" selected>(select)</option>
  <option value="1,000">user-select One</option>
  <option value="2,000">user-select Two</option>
  .
  .
</select>
```

The following is a hidden select. If a user select one from above select box, the following is selected automatically according to the value above. The option name is same as above.

```
<select class="auto-select"> 
  <option value="" selected>(select)</option>
  <option value="100,000">user-select One</option>
  <option value="200,000">user-select Two</option>
  .
  .
</select>
```

In the following div, I want display the value from the auto selected value.

```
<div class="result">Display auto select value</div>
```

Please help!

Comment: I think better option in `hidden textfield` which holds the value of the first select rather than a `hidden select`

Comment: Do you want to select the option with same name or value in the second list ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the options in the example I see and the answer you are asking are a little contradicting.

So I have different answers for 2 possible scenarios

scenario 1
If you want to select the second option with the same value instead of same name

```
$(function(){
    $('select.user-select').change(function(){ 
        var userSelect = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        $('select.auto-select').val(userSelect);
    $('.result').text($( ".auto-select option:selected" ).text());
    });
})
```

scenario 2
If you want to select the second option with same name instead of same value

```
$(function(){
    $('select.user-select').change(function(){ 
        var userSelect = $(this).find(":selected").text();
       var secondVal = $('.auto-select option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == userSelect; }).val();
       $('select.auto-select').val(secondVal);
    $('.result').text($( ".auto-select option:selected" ).text());
    });
});
```

From what I understood u should be looking for scenario 2

Comment: @user1965906 Glad that this helped you, can you mark my answer as useful.

Answer (score 1):

only with jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.user-select').change(function () {
//var val = $('.user-select').find(':selected').attr('data-id');
var val = $('.user-select').prop('selectedIndex');
$(".auto-select").prop('selectedIndex', val);
$('.result').html($(".auto-select").val());
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="user-select"> 
  <option value="" selected>(select)</option>
  <option value="1,000">user-select One</option>
  <option value="2,000">user-select Two</option>
  <option value="3,000">user-select Three</option>
  <option value="4,000">user-select Four</option>
</select>
<select class="auto-select"> 
  <option value="" selected>(select)</option>
  <option value="100,000">user-select One</option>
  <option value="200,000">user-select Two</option>
 <option value="300,000">user-select Three</option>
  <option value="400,000">user-select Four</option>
</select>

<div class="result">Display auto select value</div>
```

if you want javascript you can use this

```js
window.onload=function() { 
  document.getElementById("a").onchange=function() {
    document.getElementById("b").selectedIndex=this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-id");
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('b').value;
  }
  document.getElementById("a").onchange(); // trigger when loading
}
```

```html
<select id="a" class="user-select"> 
  <option value="" selected data-id="0">(select)</option>
  <option value="1,000" data-id="1">user-select One</option>
  <option value="2,000" data-id="2">user-select Two</option>
  <option value="3,000" data-id="3">user-select Three</option>
  <option value="4,000" data-id="4">user-select Four</option>
</select>
<select id="b" class="auto-select"> 
  <option value="" selected>(select)</option>
  <option value="100,000">user-select One</option>
  <option value="200,000">user-select Two</option>
 <option value="300,000">user-select Three</option>
  <option value="400,000">user-select Four</option>
</select>

<div id="result" class="result">Display auto select value</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is the another way to meet the need. I really appreciate it.